# Clearsigned file error when attempting to update packages

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

When I run `apt update` I get the following error:

```
E: Clearsigned file '/var/lib/apt/lists/gb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-updates_InRelease' contains unsigned lines.
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Could you advise on how I can resolve this please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove problematic lists by

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

and then retry with

```
sudo apt update
```