# 21.04 unable to get list of updates clearsigned file .. contains unsigned lines

Tags: updates

$uname -a
Linux mine 5.11.0-17-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 20:10:11 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
I am getting an error which says:
[The error from software updater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODv3C.png)

The file
/var/lib/apt/lists/gb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_hirsute-backports_InRelease
looks ok to me but I'm no expert.
Tired searching and could not find anything exactly like this.

syslog:

May 20 18:05:26 mine update-notifier.desktop[5533]: apt_pkg.Error: E:Clearsigned file '/var/lib/apt/lists/gb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_hirsute-backports_InRelease' contains unsigned lines., E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Could not add file as beaks line limit and I cant see how to add zip file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clearsigned file error when attempting to update packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339093/clearsigned-file-error-when-attempting-to-update-packages)

Comment: Not quite but gave me the clue to the answer which I found here:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82707/failing-on-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-were-invalid

Comment: This solved the issue for me:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82707/failing-on-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-were-invalid